# When does cocaine begin to induce negative health effects?

Tags: recreational-drugs

When is an addiction healthy?

What about people who don't have the same genes that make them vulnerable to addictions? People that can actually make the decision to use something only once in while and actually be truthful to their promise?

In what quantities and frequencies does cocaine begin to show permanent health negative side effects?

Are small doses every day fine? One big dose a year? Medium doses once every 3 months?

Comment: Welcome to MedicalSciences.SE! Please take the [tour] and read the [help]. For [reasons mentioned in this post](https://medicalsciences.meta.stackexchange.com/q/411) and in [ask], we require prior research information when asking questions. Please help us to help you and [edit] your question to provide more information on what you have read on this subject, what made you ask this question, and any problems you are having understanding your research. This helps to provide an answer which will be more helpful. If you found nothing, what did you Google?

Answer (score 2):

Cocaine is highly addictive and an astonishing waste of money. You also come across as attempting to normalize or explain what is probably already an addiction. I have heard the same lines from dozens of people experimenting with addictive drugs.

The main danger is cutting agents as these can include glass, crushed caffeine pills, pain-killers, amphetamines etc.

> Common cocaine additives include:
> Laundry detergent
> Laxatives
> Caffeine
> Boric acid
> Local anesthetics like procaine
> Creatine

[americanaddictioncenters.org/cocaine-treatment/cut-with](https://americanaddictioncenters.org/cocaine-treatment/cut-with)

You can also experience serious heart failure if you exhaust yourself during the high, this can be in a club, going for a run or during sexual activities.

Cocaine will definitely cause serious heart problems if you take up the habit frequently and some people die in there 40's because of this.

Mental health issues I have seen associated with cocaine abuse are by far some of the worst of any drug. You can also expect it to cause brain damage, schizophrenia and paranoia, memory issues, anger management issues, inflated sense of self and ego and you are far more likely to endanger your own life while high.

> **Short term effects**;
> confusion,
> paranoia,
> agitation,
> panic,
> anxiety,
> erratic, and
> violent behavior.

[cocain.org/effects](https://cocaine.org/effects/effects-of-cocaine-on-your-mental-health/)

Mixing cocaine with alcohol is 5 times worse for your health at least, according to most experts. Similar to a Marijuana use mixing the buds with tobacco leaf. So all of the above, but around 5 times worse.

> Other harmful effects of mixing alcohol and cocaine can include:
> The risk of cocaine overdose can be increased by mixing it with alcohol.
> Stroke.
> Intracranial haemorrhage (bleeding in the brain).
> Heart attack.
> Chronic cardiac toxicity.
> Cardiac arrhythmia.

[alcohol.org/coke](https://www.alcohol.org/mixing-with/cocaine/)

To answer your question, If the product is high quality maybe half a gram a week is reasonably safe if you are not drinking or physically exerting yourself. I would be careful though, it is unlikely but theoretically one line could kill you. It is also worth noting if you are offered a line by a stranger you should refuse it as it could be spiked with a date-rape drug and you could be robbed, raped or murdered. Just don't trust people on this drug.

Dangerous levels I would say if you ever begin using every day or two nights in a row. And if you ever get the urge to sprinkle it on your cornflakes. Then you have a 'Cocaine problem'

Answer (score 2):

To add to Chris' answer, if you consider heart attack and sudden cardiac arrest to be negative health effects, then the answer is almost any dose at any frequency.

Cocaine is a [powerful vasoconstrictor and also a powerful stimulant that raises your blood pressure and heart rate](https://www.ahajournals.org/doi/10.1161/CIRCULATIONAHA.113.002937). So if you happen to have, say, an asymptomatic partial blockage of one of your cardiac arteries and you use cocaine, it's possible the coke will turn that partial blockage into a complete blockage, resulting in a potentially fatal heart attack.

Even if you avoid such a severe outcome, since it increases the workload on your heart while limiting the heart's blood supply, it can and will exacerbate any existing cardiac conditions.

Anecdote: I lost a good friend to cocaine at the age of 33. He was an athlete and the picture of health, and yet a heart attack took him in the prime of his life  minutes after snorting coke. Autopsy confirmed the cause as described above.